# tar give exception when preserve permission/specials files across filesystems

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, tar

I am using the following tar command and tar flags in order to preserve hard and symbolic link & permissions on RHEL 8.6 version

but we get the exceptions about  `tar: '--same-order' cannot be used with '-c'`

```
tar --preserve-permissions --preserve-order -jc /var/lib/ambari-agent > /tmp/folders/2ambari-agent.tar.bz2

tar: '--same-order' cannot be used with '-c'
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
```

tar version:

```
tar --version

tar (GNU tar) 1.30
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.

more /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 (Ootpa)
uname -r
4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64
```

not clear what is wrong with my tar syntax , and what need to correct

also if I use `--same-order` without the flag `c` as previous note from tar command we get:

```
tar  --same-order --preserve-order -j  /var/lib/ambari-agent > /tmp/folders/2ambari-agent.tar.bz2
tar: '--same-order' cannot be used with 'unknown?'
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
```

so what is wrong in my syntax ?

*NOTE - on RHEL 7.x tar command works fine but not on RHEL 8.x*

reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047919/to-preserve-hard-and-symbolic-link-permissions-while-creating-tar-ball-and-doin